# Regexp for finding all regexps in project

Tags: javascript, regex, text-parsing, string-parsing

I need to optimize all regexps in a JavaScript project. I found all the ones created with new RegExp with a simple search. The problem are the ones created as literals:`/asd/`.

I am using PhPStorm so the regexp engine is Java. That means we have look behind. So i came up with this:

```
(?<=[\s=(,\[\?:;|)])\/[^*\n/][^\n/]*[^*]\/
```

This translates in give me everything that looks like `/.../` and is not preceded by one of the following:`\s= (,[?:;|)`.

1. Can a regexp be preceded by anything else?
2. Do you have a better idea?

Searching for methods used by String and RegExp classes is not acceptable(exec, replace...) because finding the declaration in some projects is very hard and requires a lot of time. Plus you can have multiple uses of the same regexp.

Comment: You cannot parse source code with regexps efficiently, only in certain contexts. Thus, a lookbehind is of little help. You may try using [`/[^\\/]*(?:\\/[^\\/]*)*/`](https://regex101.com/r/tfzR0C/1), but there will be "overfiring" with it, I am afraid. Yes, you may add a `(?<!\\)` before it, but there will still be other edge cases (theoretically).

Comment: Also note in JavaScript regex can have flags after the expression,
g - global
i - case-insensitive
m - multi-line
y - sticky search

Comment: You could search for all methods that use regular expressions: `exec`, `test`, `match`, `search`, `replace` and `split`

Comment: I don't need to parse efficiently. The only strict condition is to not miss any. And I want as little false positives as possible.

Comment: Searching for exec, test, match, search, replace and split will give me new RegExp formed regexp too and I have to go to the file and see the declaration. In JavaScript this is almost impossible for some projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My regexp was a bit off. I used this eventually:

```
(?<=[\s=(,\[\?:;|)])\/[^\n/].*?\/
```